# How to check result of jasmine test without using html reporter

Tags: javascript, jasmine

Suppose i have a browser test that does:

```
describe('Test', function() {
    it('should fail', function() {
        expect(true).toBe(false);
    });
    it ('should pass', function() {
        expect(true).toBe(true);
    });
});
```

Usually what i do is call the jasmine test reporter but i need to check the result of a test without relying on html. How do i do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could add your own [custom reporter](https://jasmine.github.io/edge/custom_reporter.html), collect the data into a report structure that fits you and in `jasmineDone` you can use the data. For more tips on how data gets sent to reporters check out the [JsApiReporter](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/blob/master/src/core/JsApiReporter.js) provided by jasmine.